PI 5 os VLC media player no HDMI sound
I have a PI 5 with dedicated HDMI monitor and keyboard and mouse.
I can play YouTube video with sound using Chromium successfully. So HDMI HW does work.
But when I use the VLC media player and try to play a file called big-buck-bunny-1080p.mp4, the video works but no sound.
BTW the "Built-In Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)" is selected as the Audio Device in VLC. Also in Tools-Audio-Output I set it to "Automatic". Also tried non Automatic setting like ALSA.
Since the HW works I must be missing a setting somewhere? Any ideas?
